# Minimize and improve code for SQL statement

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to make very simple stuff, but I came with the conclusion that my code looks very ugly and I am pretty sure that there are some ways to improve the code performance and to clearness.

How can I do it only with an SQL statement in Android SQLITE?

I have two tables: A and B.
In A table columns d, p, u. And in table B columns d, p, u. The columns have the same names.

I need to find the last added row in each table where column p is some value. And update columns d and u from table B with values of columns d and u from table A.

```
final String selection = A.p + SQL_LIKE;
final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{phone};
final String sortOrder = A.d + " DESC LIMIT 1";

final Cursor cursorA = getContentResolver().query(URI_A,
                null, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

if (cursorA != null && cursorA.moveToFirst()) {

    final long dateTimeMillis = cursorA.getLong(cursorA.getColumnIndex(A.d));            

    final String selectionB = B.p + SQL_LIKE;
    final String[] selectionArgsB = new String[]{'%' + phone};
    final Cursor cursorB = getContentResolver().query(URI_A, null,
                        selectionB, selectionArgsB, A.d + " DESC LIMIT 1");

    if(cursorB != null && cursorB.moveToFirst()){

        final EntityB entityB = new EntityB().getUnitFromCursor(cursorB);

        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(B.d, dateTimeMillis);
        contentValues.put(B.u, durationMillis);

        final String where = B._ID + SQL_ADD_VALUE;
                    final String[] whereArgs = new String[]{entityB.getId()};

        getContentResolver.update(URI_B, values, where, whereArgs)

        cursorB.close();
    }

callLogCursor.close();
}
```

Question: How can I improve my code so in future if I need something the same I do not need to write so much boilerplate and it looks more clean. I am sure this code can be changed on a single SQL statement - I think this is the best solution for such problem.

Comment: Would you like to tag whatever other language that is besides SQLite?

Comment: Please make a [mcve], consisting of some lines of "create ..." and several lines of "insert ...". the SQLite command line tool has the `.dump` feature to conventiently do so. Add the desired output for the sample content of your mcve.

Comment: If your code is basically doing what you want, then the question needs a specific problem description. Otherwise it is either off topic for being too broad or for belonging on a different site, i.e. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE B
SET d = (SELECT d
         FROM A
         WHERE p LIKE ...
         ORDER BY d DESC
         LIMIT 1),
    u = (SELECT u
         FROM A
         WHERE p LIKE ...
         ORDER BY d DESC
         LIMIT 1)
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
            FROM B
            WHERE p LIKE ...
            ORDER BY d DESC
            LIMIT 1);
```

If it is possible that `A` does not have rows for a specific `p` in `B`, then you must add another filter to the outer WHERE clause (`EXISTS (SELECT * FROM A WHERE ...)`).